# Was Air New Zealand flight NZ6 on April 16, 2020 from AKL to LAX cancelled, or did it depart?

Tags: refunds

Was Air New Zealand flight NZ6 on April 16, 2020 from AKL to LAX cancelled, or did it depart? I need to determine this information in the hope of obtaining a full refund, rather than a credit. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't help.Need a subscription to flightstats, and can't see where historical data is in flight aware. Hoping someone who is a subscriber to these sites can tell me.

Comment: Unfortunately your question then is not a good one for here, as we tend to deal with issues that have a broader scope than one exact situation - for example the other questions that are linked to the one above in my close vote, they are all almost identical to yours and are closed: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/158835/did-united-airlines-2279-from-mco-to-ewr-fly-on-april-23-2020 https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/154729/historic-flight-landing-time-for-aa-flight-2554 https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/158360/flight-cancellation-information-for-an-avianca-flight